# Can i somehow download pictures from my wordpress database?

Tags: database, wordpress

I have done a lot of research and I don't know what to do anymore. I have a database from an old wordpress site that I no longer have access to. I need to download all pictures from database or at leats find where they are stored. When I open the "field_data_field_image" table, it shows the name, id, height and width in pixels of all the images, but the image itself is not stored there.

Does anyone have idea where the pictures could be stored?

Structure of my database

[image: 1]

Thanks for you help guys ;).

Comment: The database only stores information of the image and not the image itself. So you want to get the image data while having the actual images?

Comment: As @Moishy said, the database doesn't store the image itselsf and only information about image like name or URL of the image, unless the image is stored in base64 inside the DB, but it's a nonsense to store image like this.